# App store guide line for New App in iOS SDK

Tags: ios

I have a query regarding App name.

My organization has an App on App store with the following title

```
Organization AppName
```

when we download the app from the App store, App has the following name in the device

```
Organization
```

Now the organization has made a decision to remove the older app with the name `Organization AppName` & upload a fresh app with name `Organization` on app store & for the app as well.

Is it possible to upload the new app with the same binary name having different Name (`Organization`) on the app store?

Please let me know if you are unable to get my question.

Comment: Have you tried it? AppStore uploads allow you to stage a new release without releasing it. I'd say try it and see what happens, then report back with more information if you still have questions.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Please see my other answer. Keeping this one for the clarification comments**

---

If you submit a new build, you will be able to change your app's name in Itunes Connect.

It's as simple as that.

Comment: I can change the name but I have to remove older app & then submit a new app.

Comment: You have to submit a new build, not delete the app from the store.

Comment: I got you but my management wants to remove old app due to some reasons & upload a new app.

Comment: Then you can delete the app from the store and create a new one. But all the existing users will have to go to the store and manually download it. If it's actually the same app with just a new name, tell you management to just change the name of the existing app and submit a new build. It will then get automatically updated for all users.

Answer (score 1):

There are the Info.plist keys CFBundleName and CFBundleDisplayName ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html)). This determines what the user sees on the device when you haven't localized the names with an InfoPlist.strings file. CFBundleDisplayName is the name on the home screen. CFBundleName is the name that is visible in the Settings.app

Then there are the localized versions of them if you are using InfoPlist.strings . This determines what the user sees.

And then there is the name you have chosen in ITunes Connect. This determines what you see in the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

If you completely delete the app `Organization AppName` from the store (and even if you don't) you will be able to create an app named `Organization`.

Keep in mind that in the future you won't be able to reuse the name `Organization AppName` for a new app.

[App Store Connect Help](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev28d17ed35)

> **WARNING:** If you delete your app, you can’t restore it. The SKU or app name can’t be reused in the same organization. If you’ve uploaded a build, your bundle ID can’t be reused.